# how do i retain values from pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need help with "retaining" values from one page to another example i answered the first page and proceed to the 2nd if i click "previous page" how can i keep my answers there.

Below are my codes:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //string sesrbl1;

        string selectedvalue = RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string selectedvalue2 = RadioButtonList4.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string selectedvalue3 = RadioButtonList6.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string selectedvalue4 = RadioButtonList8.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string selectedvalue5 = RadioButtonList14.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string selectedvalue6 = RadioButtonList11.SelectedValue.ToString();

        bool risk;
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBASE;Initial Catalog=TumorRegistry;User ID=sa");

    try
            {
                //Session["rb1"] = RadioButtonList12.SelectedValue;
                //Session["rb2"] = RadioButtonList3.SelectedValue;
                //Session["rb3"] = RadioButtonList5.SelectedValue;
                //Session["rb4"] = RadioButtonList7.SelectedValue;
                //Session["rb5"] = RadioButtonList13.SelectedValue;





                if (RadioButtonList12.SelectedItem.Text== "FALSE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse("False", out risk))
                    {
                        risk = false;


                        Session["rb1"] = risk;

                    }

                }
                if (RadioButtonList12.SelectedItem.Text == "TRUE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList12.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = true;
                        Session["rb1"] = risk;
                    }
                }
                if (RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Text == "FALSE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = false;
                         Session["rb2"] = risk;
                    }
                }
                if (RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Text== "TRUE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = true;
                        Session["rb2"] = risk;
                    }
                }
                if (RadioButtonList5.SelectedItem.Text == "FALSE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList5.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = false;
                         Session["rb3"] = risk;
                    }
                }
                if (RadioButtonList5.SelectedItem.Text == "TRUE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList5.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = true;
                         Session["rb3"] = risk;
                    }
                }
                if (RadioButtonList7.SelectedItem.Text == "FALSE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList7.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = false;
                         Session["rb4"] = risk;
                    }
                }
                if (RadioButtonList7.SelectedItem.Text == "TRUE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList7.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = true;
                          Session["rb4"] = risk;
                    }
                }
                if (RadioButtonList13.SelectedItem.Text == "FALSE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList13.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = false;
                         Session["rb5"] = risk;
                    }
                }
                if (RadioButtonList13.SelectedItem.Text == "TRUE")
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(RadioButtonList13.SelectedItem.Text, out risk))
                    {
                        risk = true;
                         Session["rb5"] = risk;
                    }
                }



                if (selectedvalue.ToString() == "0")
                {

                    selectedvalue = null;
                }
                else if (selectedvalue2.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    selectedvalue2 = null;
                }
                else if (selectedvalue3.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    selectedvalue3 = null;
                }
                else if (selectedvalue4.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    selectedvalue4 = null;
                }
                else if (selectedvalue5.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    selectedvalue6 = null;
                }



                //Session["rb1"] = RadioButtonList12.SelectedValue;
                //Session["rb2"] = RadioButtonList3.SelectedValue;
                //Session["rb3"] = RadioButtonList5.SelectedValue;
                //Session["rb4"] = RadioButtonList7.SelectedValue;
                //Session["rb5"] = RadioButtonList13.SelectedValue;



        //sending values to the submit button next page 
                Session["Holdtextbox1"] = RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Session["Holdtextbox2"] = RadioButtonList4.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Session["Holdtextbox3"] = RadioButtonList6.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Session["Holdtextbox4"] = RadioButtonList8.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Session["Holdtextbox5"] = RadioButtonList14.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Session["Holdtextbox6"] = RadioButtonList11.SelectedValue.ToString();



                selectedvalue = Session["Holdtextbox1"].ToString();
                selectedvalue2 = Session["Holdtextbox2"].ToString();
                selectedvalue3 = Session["Holdtextbox3"].ToString();
                selectedvalue4 = Session["Holdtextbox4"].ToString();
                selectedvalue5 = Session["Holdtextbox5"].ToString();
                selectedvalue6 = Session["Holdtextbox6"].ToString();






                    Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");



               } 

              catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
```

that's for the first page

here's for the 2nd page i have 2 buttons button 1  and 2

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        ////Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.back(); return false;");
        //   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    } 



       public void SaveRecord()
        {
            try
            {
                Holdtextbox1.Text = Session["Holdtextbox1"].ToString();
                Holdtextbox2.Text = Session["Holdtextbox2"].ToString();
                Holdtextbox3.Text = Session["Holdtextbox3"].ToString();
                Holdtextbox4.Text = Session["Holdtextbox4"].ToString();
                Holdtextbox5.Text = Session["Holdtextbox5"].ToString();
                Holdtextbox6.Text = Session["Holdtextbox6"].ToString();
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
                SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter();

                // string SqlInsert = "Insert into tbTRcBase (HPN,ISH, Asthma, DM, OtherCo,HPNTreatment, ISHTreatment,AsthmaTreatment, DMTreatment, OtherCoTreatment,SecondHandSmoke,Smoker, StopSmoking , Occupation , CancerFamilyHistory, FamilyWithCancer,ParentWithCancer) values ('" + bitsess.Text + "','" + bitsess2.Text + "','" + bitsess3.Text + "','" + bitsess4.Text + "','" + bitsess5.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox1.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox2.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox3.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox4.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox5.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox6.Text + "','" + rb1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + rb2.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + cb1.Text + "','" + rb3.Text + "','" + cb2.Text + "','" + rb4.Text + "')";    
                string SqlInsert = "Insert into tbTRcBase (HPN,ISH, Asthma, DM, OtherCo,HPNTreatment, ISHTreatment,AsthmaTreatment, DMTreatment, OtherCoTreatment,SecondHandSmoke,Smoker, StopSmoking , Occupation , CancerFamilyHistory, FamilyWithCancer,ParentWithCancer) values ('" + Session["rb1"] + "','" + Session["rb2"] + "','" + Session["rb3"] + "','" + Session["rb4"] + "','" + Session["rb5"] + "','" + Holdtextbox1.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox2.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox3.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox4.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox5.Text + "','" + Holdtextbox6.Text + "','" + rb1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + rb2.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + cb1.Text + "','" + rb3.Text + "','" + cb2.Text + "','" + rb4.Text + "')";
                //   string SqlInsert = "Insert into tbTRcBase (HPN, HPNTreatment) values ('" + Session["rb1"] + "','" + Holdtextbox1.Text + "')";   
                DA = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlInsert, sqlcon);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DA.Fill(dt);
                sqlcon.Close();
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('" + " Data has been saved " + "')</script>");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('" + e.Message + "')</script>");
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem, does it work?

Comment: My two cents, don't redirect. You're using web forms, use `Asp:panels` to hide and show your respective areas on post back in response to your button clicks. All state will be maintained by `ViewState`

Comment: this work i just don't how to hold off the variables in the previous page because when i go back to it, i refreshes because of post back

Answer (score 0):

For retaining the values on the previous page, you would have to make use of those `Session` variables that you have stored on the same page before you pass them onto the next page.

On the `Page_Load` event of the previous page, make a function that just binds the respective controls based on the values of those Session variables.

Something like this :

```
public void BindData()
{
    Holdtextbox1.Text = Session["Holdtextbox1"].ToString();
    .
    .
    .
    //all your controls and the Session values.
}
```

Hope this helps.